# How to map the symmetry property of the lattice unit cell to the symmetry properties of eigen modes

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, group-theory, group-representations, graphene

For example, in $\mathbf{r}$ space, a honeycomb lattice (like graphene) has C6v symmetry about the center of the unit cell. The ground state (singlet) eigen mode has C6v symmetry and the 1st order state (doublet) eigen modes has C3v symmetry, in $\mathbf{r}$ space.

Is there a general rule that maps the symmetry group of the lattice unit cell to the symmetry groups of the eigen modes?

Comment: The only thing you can say in general is that the eigenstates at a fixed energy form a representation of the group. Any representation can occur, however. The ground state doesn't even have to be invariant. There are charge-density-waves and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is this basically saying that the symmetry groups of the eigen modes can be any subgroup of the symmetry group of the unit cell?

Comment: Something like that. The symmetries which fix an eigenstate can form any normal subgroup of the full space group. The other elements not in that subgroup will map this eigenstate to different eigenstates of the same energy.